# Why does mulberry have so many different endings? (桑葚、桑椹、桑甚、桑黮)？

Tags: writing

I always just assumed mulberry was 桑葚. I was going through some materials though and came across many variants:

- 桑椹
- 桑甚
- 桑黮

It's not as if they are even traditional or simplified variants. What's up with all these different suffixes (葚, 椹, 甚, 黮) for mulberry?

Comment: Are you sure that they’re different endings? Just a guess, but it looks like different semantic indicators were added to the same ending because the spelling was not standardised.

Comment: @droooze that’s a point, and you might just be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 桑**葚**（sāng shèn），又作桑**椹**，桑树的成熟果实，为桑科植物桑树的果穗。又名桑椹子、桑蔗、桑枣、桑果、桑泡儿，乌椹等。
>
> **黮**
> dàn
> 云黑色：“当时黮闇犹承误，末俗纷纭更乱真。”
> shèn
> 古通“葚”，桑果：“食我桑黮。”

So it seems that 桑椹 and 桑葚 are the same. And 黮 is the interchangeability character of 葚 in ancient time. While 甚 should be a wrong word since I didn't find any explanation related to 桑甚.

Comment: 桑甚 is recorded in *ABC* and *Grand Ricci*.